# Inject a list of injected instances

Tags: java, scala, dependency-injection, guice

I have a service that exposes a method. I have an implementation of that method that can aggregate the results of other implementations of the same service. How do I inject the list of other implementations to that aggregating implementations via injection? For example:

I have a trait `DictionaryProvider` which provides `get( s: String )`  method. My `MultipleDictionaryProvider` implementation can aggregate other implementations, say, `OxfordDictionaryAndColorProvider` and `WebsterDictionaryAndShapeProvider`.

```
    class OxfordDictionaryAndColorProvider (p: Param ) extends DictionaryProvider with ColorProvider
    class WebsterDictionaryAndShapeProvider extends DictionaryProvider with ShapeProvider

    class MultipleDictionaryProvider( 
         l: List[ DictionaryProvider ]
    )
    {
            def get(){ /*Sequence of l matters*/  }
    }
    extends DictionaryProvider
```

Both `OxfordDictionaryAndColorProvider` and `WebsterDictionaryAndShapeProvider` are constructed via injection. They both have some role outside providing dictionaries and they have a singleton instance constructed anyway, as a `ColorProvider` and `ShapeProvider` respectively.

I want to bind my `DictionaryProvider` to a `MultipleDictionaryProvider`. How should I do that such that the sequence of elements in l inside can be as I want? (`OxfordDictionaryAndColorProvider` followed by `WebsterDictionaryAndShapeProvider` for this particular case) (the order should be easy to change and should require change at only one place)

EDIT: I made an edit to the question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Guice, and you have a fixed list of `DictionaryProvider` objects, an easy way is to simply bind `DictonaryProvider` to `MultipleDictionaryProvider`, and implement a provider method in your injector module for `List[DictionaryProvider]`:

```
@Provides
def makeProviderList(
        oxford: OxfordDictionaryProvider,
        webster: WebsterDictionaryProvider): List[DictionaryProvider] =
    List(oxford, webster)
```

Guice will instantiate `OxfordDictinaryProvider` and `WebsterDictionaryProvider`, call your provider method, and instantiate `MultipleDictionaryProvider` with the returned list.

If you want to avoid specific class names in your provider function signature, a useful technique is to use annotated types, for example with `@Named`:

```
@Provides
def makeProviderList(
    @Named("oxford") oxford: DictionaryProvider,
    @Named("webster") webster: DictionaryProvider) = List(oxford, webster)
```

While this code still seems to contain lot of dictionary-specific information, the implementation classes are in fact not specified, they need to be bound in the module class like this:

```
bind(classOf[DictionaryProvider])
    .annotatedWith(Names.named("oxford"))
    .to(classOf[OxfordDictionaryProvider])
```

The number and kind of dictionaries are still hardcoded. To make that more flexible, you will need to take instantiation in your own hand:

```
val dictList = List("oxford", "webster")

@Provides
def makeProviderList(injector: Injector) =
    dictList.map(dictName => injector.getInstance(
        Key.get(classOf[DictionaryProvider], Names.named(dictName))))
```

Note that `dictList` may be determined at runtime, it may even be injected using this binding:

```
bind(Key.get(new TypeLiteral[List[String]](){}))
    .toInstance(List("oxford", "webster"))
```

Comment: I don't like that the parameter types are hardcoded. They could be any of 10 and I don't want to be changing them manually at multiple places. I just want to change them once at the place where I decide which ones to use.

Comment: Well, the provider function is the single place where you decide :)

Comment: The key is that you want the injector create different `DictionaryProvider` instances, and for that, the injector must know which ones to create. Alternative approaches are using annotated `DictonaryProvider` arguments (e.g. `@Named`) which still hardcodes the same information, or asking for an injector in the argument list and constructing the list elements by calling `getInstance`. The latter will give you more freedom, making it even possible to select dictionaries at runtime.